# Alert when sql log file become too big?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, email, notifications

I need to create an application or service which notifies when the log file increases above a certain size. Either an email or something else.

Comment: You might want to ask on serverfault whether this is something that SQL Server can be told to do by itself. You'll have to specify which SQL Server version you're using, though.

Comment: mssql 2008 (sorry about that )

Comment: I don't see how this is off-topic.

Comment: how is it off topic ..its a notification system through .net!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the whole scripted agent task with the above logic in it.  See 3 variables to set at the top.  (Operator name can be null if you only want to generate a windows application log error)

```
USE [msdb]
GO
Declare @AdminUserName varchar(255)
Declare @Operator varchar(255)
Declare @EmailNotify bit
Set @AdminUserName = N'YOUR SYSADMIN USER'
set @Operator = N'YOUR OPERATOR NAME'
Set @EmailNotify = 1


/****** Object:  Job [Transaction Logfile Size Monitoring]    Script Date: 08/02/2012 15:39:11 ******/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
/****** Object:  JobCategory [[Uncategorized (Local)]]]    Script Date: 08/02/2012 15:39:11 ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END
Declare @NotifyLevel int
If @EmailNotify = 1 Begin 
set @NotifyLevel =2 end 
else begin
set @NotifyLevel=0 
set @Operator=null
end

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'Transaction Logfile Size Monitoring', 
            @enabled=1, 
            @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
            @notify_level_email=@NotifyLevel, 
            @notify_level_netsend=0, 
            @notify_level_page=0, 
            @delete_level=0, 
            @description=N'No description available.', 
            @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
            @owner_login_name=@AdminUserName, 
            @notify_email_operator_name=@Operator, @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [Monitor Logfile Size]    Script Date: 08/02/2012 15:39:11 ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Monitor Logfile Size', 
            @step_id=1, 
            @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
            @on_success_action=1, 
            @on_success_step_id=0, 
            @on_fail_action=2, 
            @on_fail_step_id=0, 
            @retry_attempts=0, 
            @retry_interval=0, 
            @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
            @command=N'Declare @LogSize int;
Declare @LogName varchar(255);
Declare @LogFile varchar(2000);

select  Top 1 @LogName=name,@LogFile=physical_name,@LogSize = convert(float,size) * 8192 / (1024 * 1024) from    sys.master_files
where   type_desc = ''LOG'' Order by size desc

IF (@LogSize > 10240)
BEGIN
Declare @AlertString varchar(5000)
set @AlertString = @LogName + '' : '' + @LogFile + '' has reached a size of '' + Convert(varchar(20),@LogSize) + '' MB.''
RAISERROR(@AlertString, 18,1) with LOG
END
ELSE
BEGIN
RAISERROR(''Transaction Log monitoring complete'', 0, 1)
END', 
            @database_name=N'master', 
            @flags=4
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'Hourly Logfile Check', 
            @enabled=1, 
            @freq_type=4, 
            @freq_interval=1, 
            @freq_subday_type=8, 
            @freq_subday_interval=1, 
            @freq_relative_interval=0, 
            @freq_recurrence_factor=0, 
            @active_start_date=20120802, 
            @active_end_date=99991231, 
                @active_start_time=0, 
            @active_end_time=235959, 
            @schedule_uid=N'18435d90-4ca0-4c7a-a8a9-c81f347ba32c'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:

GO
```

Answer (score 3):

The [sys.master_files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186782.aspx) view contains the size of the log file(s):

```
select  size * 8192 / (1024 * 1024) as [Size in MB]
from    sys.master_files
where   type_desc = 'LOG'
        and database_id = db_id('NameOfYourDatabase')
```

It lists the size in 8KB blocks.

You could check the size in a SQL Agent scheduled task, and if it exceeds a certain size, send an email with [sp_send_dbmail](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/).